# Дано натуральное n, строка с n чисел. Заменить нулевые елементы на сумму двух соседниз элементов(нуль не может быть крайним элементом)

Tags: python, строки

Код на котором я остановился, ничего не получается

```
x = input()
for i in x.split():
   

     s = int(i)
        if i == 0:
            y = x[i-1] + [i+1]
        x = x.replace("0", y)
        print(x)
```

По возможности простой код. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Несколько нулей подряд может быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

скажите, а что это за код?

```
y = x[i-1] + [i+1]
```

1. `[i+1]` - это что, где название списка?
2. `x` - это строка, вы ее разбили на слова только в цикле `for`, поэтому обращаясь по индексу к строке вы обращаетесь к букве строки
3. и складываете вы буквы (а лучшем случае, если бы не было ошибки 2)) вы бы складывали слова, а не числа, поскольку в целые числа вы не переводите

далее задание не очень чёткое, например что делать с последовательностью `1 0 0 0 2`, что должно получиться `1 1 0 2 2`? или надо избавиться вообще от нулей и получить `1 1 3 2 2`

В остальном код правильный (правда и кода то не осталось, если убрать ошибки :))

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

for i in range(1, len(arr) - 1):
    if arr[i] == 0:
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + arr[i + 1]

print(*arr)
```

Этот код переварит все и не оставит `0` вообще

А теперь можно немного поизвращаться:

Код, который оставит нули как в описанном выше примере:

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

res = arr[:1] + [arr[i - 1] + arr[i + 1] if arr[i] == 0 else arr[i] for i in range(1, len(arr) - 1)] + arr[-1:]

print(*res)
```

Ну и первоначальный код можно немного поджать:

```
for i in range(1, len(arr) - 1):
    arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + arr[i + 1] if arr[i] == 0 else arr[i]
```

Comment: Вы гений!! Очень спасибо. Не знаю как допустил первую ошибку, а 2 и 3 ошибки есть в этом коде, я перед этим пытался использовать много методов, но ничего не получалось, не знал как правильно свои мысли отобразить на коде, очень спасибо